# Change selection color for all elements on the page through CSS

Tags: html, css

How to change selection color (not only for text but) for all the elements on the page.

I tried:

```
::-moz-selection { /* Code for Firefox */
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
}

::selection {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
}
```

but that did not change selection color for images, which were still blue when selected.

Comment: @XLXMXNT So if I use the code I mentioned above and also the one mentioned in the answer of the question, there will be no more such elements left, which will have default selection color?

Comment: Hi @rGun that is correct – the answers there describe that the problem may not be solvable using only CSS (see the comments). Looking into this issue myself, `::selection` worked absolutely fine for me, so I have found that it may be a browser-specific or even platform-specific issue.